# Set onclick function to anchor element in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm developing a laravel application, there I want to set a onclick function to Html `anchor` element. 
So I created it as following way.

In my blade view

```
<a class='compon' id="{{$value[1]}}" href="#" onclick="return myFunction();">
    <div class="mq-friends thumbnail">
       <div class="mq-friends-footer">
          <small>{{$value[0]}}</small>
       </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

my `resources/assets/js/app.js`

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log('whatever');
    return true;
}
```

This is not working, (I also carefully checked that app.js file has built into `public/js/app.js` using laravel-mix (`npm run dev`) and the function `myFunction()` is there.)

What I want to know is why it is not working? is there any problem with `blade`?

Note: This is clearly working when I insert this script into my same blade view without adding to js file:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
     function myFunction()
     {
          console.log('whatever');
          return true;
     }
</script>
```

Comment: notice the difference between the definition and the call. onclick="return **my**Function();" while function **the**Function() {

Comment: In case it helped you, may I write it as an answer for your approval?

Comment: Oops sorry, that is not the case, it is a mistake when I asked the question, because I changed it very simply to understand as a question appropriate here..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Im not 100% sure of it, but:

I think when you want to bind the anchor `onclick` event, you need to bind the function to the window object, like this in your app.js:

```
  window.myFunction = function(ev) {
     console.log(ev)
  });
```

In my case it solved.

Another way (seems to be the recommended one) is binding in an [unobtrusive way](http://blog.socialcast.com/unobtrusive-javascript-2/).

Hope it helps o/